# Supervisor ubuntu 12.04 gunicorn nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Здравствуйте.
Как сделать так, чтобы приложение поднималось после перезагрузки сервака ?
После самой перезагрузки, мне нужно ввести логин и пароль, затем убить процесс, который автоматически запускается `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord`, затем, мне нужно обозначить где находится конфиг:

`sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`,

`sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

После чего мой app запускается.

В visudo изначально пытался сделать так:

```
myappuser  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart app
```

Сама команда работает до перезагрузки, но после, требует проведения операций, указанных выше.

Как быть? 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в /etc/init.d создать файл, который будет неким сервисом по управлению этого ПО. указать файл как стартап скрипт. и еще дать права на запуск и выполнение

Comment: @senior-automator, а как быть с тем, что нужно переопределять путь конфига и убивать процесс, который запускается автоматически  ?

Comment: укажите в этом скрипте какой конфиг нужен  и запускайте.